# index.html is not accessing app.js nor data.js after it is relocated to a subfolder 'templates'

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I have a working static web page where the index.html successfully reads the style from `css/style.css`, the data from `js/data.js` and the logic from `js/app.js`.  Here are the exact code inside index.html:

- for the style: `link href="static/css/style.css`
- for the data: `script src="static/js/data.js`
- for the logic: `script src="static/js/app.js`

The problem is that when I run a Flask python app to simply load the `index.html`, I had to move the `index.html` inside a new folder call 'templates'.  When I do that the web page loads, and even the style is loaded, even though I did not change the route for the `css/style.css`.  However, the `index.html` does not access the data.js nor the app.js.  I know I have to modify the routes' syntax in the codes I shared above, but I cannot determine what the route is.  I have tried starting with `'frontend3/...'` but it did not work.

[frontend2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K40Mx.png) file/folder structure where `index.html` fetched `data.js` and `app.js`.  There is no app.py flask application.  The index.html reads data.js and app.js.

[frontend3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs0U6.png) file/folder structure where index.html does not fetch data.js and app.js.  There is a flask app (app.py), which the convention requires me to place index.html inside 'templates' folder.

I know I missing something simple.  Please help.  Thank you.

Comment: Improved formatting and highlighted code and path text.

Answer (score 1):

Those links are relative, and need to be absolute. The simple way to do that is to prefix the paths with '/'. E.g.,

```
href="/static/css/style.css"
```

The Flask way is to use `url_for` in your templates

```
href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}"
```

Either will work.

Comment: Thank you Dan for the reply.  I tried it but it did not work. Whether I try your suggestion below or not, index.html does access the css for style.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">

But I tried it with links to app.js and data.js, and the index.html still does not read it. 

  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/data.js') }}"> type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/app.js') }}"> type="text/javascript"></script>

But it did not work.  The app.js & data.js are NOT accessed by index.html.

Comment: The issue may not be with the syntax for pointing to app.js and data.js in the index.html.  I get this error 'd3.json(...).then is not a function' when I look in the developer tools of the browser.  Is there an issue running d3.json and the full stack application, at the same time by entering python app.py which launches a flask app that returns index.html?

Comment: Ah. Might it be possible that you're using older documentation/examples and a current d3.js? You might be running in to https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-50

Comment: Thanks for follow up. I do not understand how I would modify the d3 scripts in  app.js.  I do not want to just add .then by trial and error.  They are:

// get table references
var tbody = d3.select("tbody");

// prevent refresh 
d3.event.preventDefault();

// Get merchant name value from the filter
  var merc = d3.select("#Merchant").property("value");
  
  // Get result type value from the filter
  var answer = d3.select("#Results").property("value");

// build the filtered table
  buildTable(shortFilter);
  d3.select("li").text(`Accuracy:  ${filteredData[0,0].ACCU}`);

Comment: Also, I think the d3 version that I am using is 4.  I am not 100% sure.  This is the script in the index.html  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.js"></script>

Comment: Hi Dave!  I fixed it.  Your suggestion to use href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}" and do that for app.js and data.js worked.  d3 error was unrelated. It was from another program and  I was not clearing the cache in the browser.  Everything is working now!  Thanks again for your help.